Mac OS Sonoma (14.6.1) Brackets (2.2) error code EACCES encountered while starting the php process
UPDATE (Sat 28 Sep 2024):
I've removed the quotes around the two booleans in the php json to no effect.
I'm running Brackets v2.2 on Mac OS Sonoma v14.6.1 and I'm getting the following error message:
error code EACCES encountered while starting the php process
I was having a json syntax error in brackets.json, but I believe I've fixed this. In any case, this is my current brackets.json in case the error is in it but is not a syntax error:
{
    "brackets-eslint.gutterMarks": true,
    "brackets-eslint.useLocalESLint": false,
    "fonts.fontSize": "14px",
    "fonts.fontFamily": "'SourceCodePro-Medium', ＭＳ ゴシック, 'MS Gothic', monospace",
    "php": {
    "enablePhpTooling": true, 
    "executablePath": "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.3.11/bin",
    "memoryLimit": "4095M", 
    "validateOnType": false
    }
}

Brakcets hangs (I can't select either editing window or make changes within either window) but is not "unresponsive" according to Force Quit Applications.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
